# How to load .pth file?

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx

I am given a pytorch model from [this repository](https://github.com/leoxiaobin/deep-high-resolution-net.pytorch) and I have to convert it to tflite.
Here's the code:

```
def get_torch_model(model_path):
    """
    Loads state-dict into model and creates an instance.
    """
    model= torch.load(model_path)
    return model
```

```
# Conversion
import torch
from torchvision import transforms

import onnx

import cv2
import numpy as np
import onnx
import tensorflow as tf
import torch
from PIL import Image

import torch.onnx

image, tf_lite_image, sample_input = get_sample_input("crop.jpg")
torch_model = get_torch_model("pose_resnet_152_256x256.pth")

ONNX_FILE = "./m_model.onnx"
```

Up until here everything runs smoothly. But when I run the below cell:

```
torch.onnx.export(
        model=torch_model,
        args=sample_input,
        f=ONNX_FILE,
        verbose=False,
        export_params=True,
        do_constant_folding=False,  # fold constant values for optimization
        input_names=['input'],
        opset_version=10,
        output_names=['output']
)

onnx_model = onnx.load(ONNX_FILE)

onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)
```

The complete log of error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-15df717ec276> in <module>
      8         input_names=['input'],
      9         opset_version=10,
---> 10         output_names=['output']
     11 )
     12 

~\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\__init__.py in export(model, args, f, export_params, verbose, training, input_names, output_names, aten, export_raw_ir, operator_export_type, opset_version, _retain_param_name, do_constant_folding, example_outputs, strip_doc_string, dynamic_axes, keep_initializers_as_inputs, custom_opsets, enable_onnx_checker, use_external_data_format)
    274                         do_constant_folding, example_outputs,
    275                         strip_doc_string, dynamic_axes, keep_initializers_as_inputs,
--> 276                         custom_opsets, enable_onnx_checker, use_external_data_format)
    277 
    278 

~\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\utils.py in export(model, args, f, export_params, verbose, training, input_names, output_names, aten, export_raw_ir, operator_export_type, opset_version, _retain_param_name, do_constant_folding, example_outputs, strip_doc_string, dynamic_axes, keep_initializers_as_inputs, custom_opsets, enable_onnx_checker, use_external_data_format)
     92             dynamic_axes=dynamic_axes, keep_initializers_as_inputs=keep_initializers_as_inputs,
     93             custom_opsets=custom_opsets, enable_onnx_checker=enable_onnx_checker,
---> 94             use_external_data_format=use_external_data_format)
     95 
     96 

~\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\utils.py in _export(model, args, f, export_params, verbose, training, input_names, output_names, operator_export_type, export_type, example_outputs, opset_version, _retain_param_name, do_constant_folding, strip_doc_string, dynamic_axes, keep_initializers_as_inputs, fixed_batch_size, custom_opsets, add_node_names, enable_onnx_checker, use_external_data_format, onnx_shape_inference, use_new_jit_passes)
    677         _set_opset_version(opset_version)
    678         _set_operator_export_type(operator_export_type)
--> 679         with select_model_mode_for_export(model, training):
    680             val_keep_init_as_ip = _decide_keep_init_as_input(keep_initializers_as_inputs,
    681                                                              operator_export_type,

~\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\contextlib.py in __enter__(self)
     79     def __enter__(self):
     80         try:
---> 81             return next(self.gen)
     82         except StopIteration:
     83             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None

~\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\utils.py in select_model_mode_for_export(model, mode)
     36 def select_model_mode_for_export(model, mode):
     37     if not isinstance(model, torch.jit.ScriptFunction):
---> 38         is_originally_training = model.training
     39 
     40         if mode is None:

AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'training'
```

This error occurs when I use `torch.onnx.export()` .

Please let me know whats going wrong here.
Am I not loading the weights properly? If not then how do I load the model? I don't know the class, or architecture details so how do I use `model.load_state_dict()` ?

Comment: I guess you are loading the wrong object, it's saying you have an attribute error, this usually comes when you are trying to access an attribute the object doesn't have. So check if you loaded the model or some other object. Also please tell the exact statement of the second cell that caused this error.

Comment: I am not sure but I dont think I am loading any wrong object. The error is pointing to line  ```output_names=['output']``` of the torch.onnx.export() I tried removing that so it just points to the line before.

Comment: Print the model object and check if it prints something like a tuple containing torch.nn modules. It will sure print a OrderedDict object. The actual model should be within the OrderedDict. Use indexing to access the model. Don't pass the OrderedDict object.

Comment: @Shai answer is correct, you need to import the class of the model to load the trained weights.

Answer (score 2):

A `.pth` binary file in pytorch does NOT store the model, but only its trained weights. You need to `import` the `class` (a derived `class` of `torch.nn.Module`) that implements the *functionality* of the model. Once you have the functionality, you can load the trained weights to get a particular instance of the model to work with.

Comment: Okay I understand. But I do not get what ```class``` should I ```import````.  I dont think I can just create a class because if I do then there will be a mismatch in torch.size(s).

Comment: you need the code (implementation) that was used when trained the weights (.pth)